# How to refresh a Shapefile hexagon layer when joined DB changes

Tags: qgis

I have a table that I have created a spatial join with a layer that is a polygon grid (hexagons) this is fine and gives me the data I am looking for within each individual hexagon.

However, my underlying table will have data added to it (which updates ok when the SQL database receives new data). The spatial join layer does not update, so can this be refreshed (or do I need to create a new spatial join) and how is it achieved.

Comment: How is the spatial join created currently?

Comment: Hi I used MMQGIS >Combine>Spatial Join then used the polygon layer as the target and the Data Table as the source.

Comment: If you could but the polygon layer in SQL server you can do the the join there and raise the result to QGIS as a view. Don't know about SQL server but PostgreSQL/PostGIS will auto update the view when the map is refreshed/zoomed/panned in QGIS and the base tables has been updated.